# What is wrong with this code? error "missing } after property list"

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this jquery?

```
function() {  
var testscore =100; //testvalue to enter into the mysql database
$.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "ajax.php",  
                data: testscore,  
                success: function(){  
                $('#hiddendiv').fadeIn();};  

            })
            };
```

I keep getting the following error

```
missing } after property list
[Break On This Error] $('#hiddendiv').fadeIn();};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semi-colon at the end of the following line is what is breaking the code:

```
$('#hiddendiv').fadeIn();};
```

You are inside an object literal, so you delimit the property values with a comma and not a semi-colon.

You may be able to spot such issues more easily if you format your code properly:

```
function() {  
  var testscore =100; //testvalue to enter into the mysql database
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "ajax.php",  
    data: testscore,  
    success: function(){  
      $('#hiddendiv').fadeIn();
    } 
  });
};
```

Comment: You just beat me to it. Though I must say that semi-colon is not superfluous. It is actually incorrect.

Comment: @rdumont, You are correct.  Someone edited my answer and in doing so, changed the context of my answer!

Comment: @Gazler Thanks for your answer. I'll try to work on making my code more readable.